# Should Equivalent Linear Codes be of the same dimension?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, coding-theory

Firstly, let me remind you the definition of two equivalent linear codes. Let $\alpha \in \Bbb F_q^*$. We define the following maps:

For any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, we define the map 
\begin{align*}
f_\sigma: \Bbb F_q^n \longrightarrow \Bbb F_q^n, \
(x_1,\dots,x_n) \longmapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
f_i^{\alpha}: \Bbb F_q^n \longrightarrow \Bbb F_q^n, \
(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)  \longmapsto  (x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},\alpha x_i,x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)
\end{align*}
where $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

**Definition.** Let $C_1,C_2\leq \Bbb F_q^n$ be two  $q$-ary linear codes of length $n$. We say that $C_1$ is **equivalent** to $C_2$ and we write $C_1\sim C_2$, if there is a map $h:\Bbb F_q^n \longrightarrow \Bbb F_q^n$, which is a composition of maps of the form $f_\sigma$ and $f_i^\alpha$, such that $h(C_1)=C_2$.

---

***Question.*** Let $C_1\sim C_2$ be two equivalent codes. By definition both these codes must be of length $n$ and of same size $M$. But what about their dimension? Should it be tha same? And if not, could you give a counter example?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the size of a linear code be $q^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the code? So if you already know that the sizes are equal, then their dimensions must be equal. Alternatively, you can see that $f_\sigma$ and $f_\sigma^\alpha$ are always isomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ and hence preserve the dimension of subspaces.

Comment: @Joppy Thank you for your comment. For the first part, suppose that $C_1\sim C_2$ are two equivalent $(n,M)$-codes over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Now suppose that $\dim C_1=k$. Then, its size will be $M=|C_1|=|C_2|=q^k$. Then, can we conclude that $\dim C_2=\dim C_1=k$? And if yes, why?

Comment: If a field has $q$ elements, then a $d$-dimensional vector space over that field has $q^d$ elements. This is because after picking a basis, every vector can be written down as a linear combination of that basis, with $d$ independent scalars in the linear combination, and $q$ choices for each scalar.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. But if I understand properly, I am asking given that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $|V_1|=|V_2|$ (ie having the same number of elements), then how do we conclude that $\dim V_1=\dim V_2$? In other words I can't understand the phrase "sizes are equal, then their dimensions must be equal". Could you please explain this point?

Comment: If $q^{d_1} = q^{d_2}$ for an integer $q \geq 2$, then $d_1 = d_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1 \sim C_2$. Then by definition there is a map $h: \mathbb{F}_q^n \to \mathbb{F}_q^n$ such that $h(C_1) = C_2$. Note that this map $h$ is in fact the composition of maps that are all linear isomorphisms. Thus $h$ itself is a linear isomorphism. We thus get the even stronger statement that $C_1 \cong C_2$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector spaces. In particular, their dimensions must be equal.