# In a vector space over a finite field, must two subspaces with the same cardinality have the same dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

While I was studying some *Coding Theory*, I stumbled on a Linear Algebra over $\mathbb{F}_q$ issue.
In particular, this question generalises a question I asked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3602595/326865) post.

Let $q=p^n$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is a positive integer and we denote by $\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field of order $q$.

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $V_1,V_2\leq V$ are its subspaces and $\dim V_1=k<\infty$.

As one can see, the cardinality of $V_1$ is $|V_1|=q^k$. Now suppose moreover that $|V_2|=|V_1|=q^k$.

My question is if we  can claim that in this case we also have $$\dim V_2=\dim V_1 = k.$$

If this is not correct, can I have a counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. If $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ is a basis, then every element can be expressed uniquely in the form
$$\alpha_1v_1+\cdots + \alpha_rv_r$$
and since each $\alpha_i$ has $q$ choices, we see that the number of possible vectors is exactly $q^r$.

Thus, if $V$ is a vector space over a finite field with $q$ elements, then $\dim(V)=r$ if and only if $|V|=q^r$.

In particular, since two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension (in the sense of cardinality) it follows that for vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a finite field, the following are equivalent:

1. $V$ is isomorphic to $W$;
2. $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$;
3. $|V|=|W|$.

Comment: Dear Arturo, thank you for your answer. Let me try to put it in another words: So, suppose $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}\subseteq V_2$ is a basis of $V_2$ and $|V_2|=q^k.$ Then, all the elements of $V_2$ are precisely of the form $\alpha_1v_1+\cdots + \alpha_rv_r$, where $\alpha_i$ run over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (and so we have $q$ choices for each, as you metioned). But then, in order to obtain $q^k$ such elements, the only possibility is $r=k$. Right?

Comment: @Chris Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Berci Thank you very much.